# Jquery scroll until element reaches top

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have arrows in the center of my web pages at the end of sections and I was these to allow users to scroll to the next section on click.  I have the following code where the first click works but subsequent clicks do not scroll even though the function is being called each time.

```
$('.scroll').on('click', function(event) {
alert('scroll');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".scroll").offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

Can anyone assist?  https://jsfiddle.net/avL459sm/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use current `.scroll` element you clicked on.

Look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/avL459sm/3/

Comment: Thanks, its obvious now you pointed it out.  Just need to use 'this'.

Comment: @LeeTee mark this answer as correct if this fixed your problem.

Comment: Give me chance!  I had to wait for 10 minutes before I could mark it as correct.   Not sure why stackoverflow have these strange rules!